# resignFirstResponder not getting called inside textFieldShouldClear

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to implement search bar in one of my page.

**I am not using regular search bar due to its design.**

What I have is as below.

```
UIImageView above UIView (textfield background)
UITextField above UIImageView (textfield)
```

I am using `delegates` for `UITextField`.

In code I have `searchTF.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;` to show the clear button.

Search is working fine but the problem is in delegate of clear button.

I have below code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == searchTF) {

        NSLog(@"clicked clear button");
        [textField resignFirstResponder]; // this is not working
        // also below is not working
        // [searchTF resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

When I click clear button, I get NSLog of text "clicked clear button", however the keyboard doesn't get dismissed.

Any idea why keyboard is not getting dismissed when I have

---

### Edit 1

Even I tried as below using `[self.view endEditing:YES];`, but still its not working.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == searchTF) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self hideAllKeyboards];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter : please comment for downvote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional to my comment I made some testing and here are my results:

I've just implemented a `UITextField` with all delegate methods like this:

```c
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Should Clear");
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Begin editing");
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"End editing");
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Should begin editing");
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Should end editing");
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  NSLog(@"Change char");
  return YES;
}
```

As soon as you hit the clear button the log outputs:

```
2014-07-26 11:08:44.558 Test[36330:60b] Should Clear
2014-07-26 11:08:44.558 Test[36330:60b] Should end editing
2014-07-26 11:08:44.559 Test[36330:60b] End editing
2014-07-26 11:08:44.560 Test[36330:60b] Should begin editing
2014-07-26 11:08:44.561 Test[36330:60b] Begin editing
```

As you can see the `shouldBeginEditing`and the `didBeginEditing` methods get called after clearing so the `resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldshouldClear` gets called just before a new `becomeFirstResponder` is called by `shouldBeginEditing` or `didBeginEditing`.

Comment: +1 : for detail explanation... Now I understand what was going... thanks for making it clear...

Comment: Mh I think the way you solved the problem is more a workaround because it could be that your timer is quicker than the delegate methods e.g. on slower devices. A better solution would be to implement `textFieldShouldClear` like this `[textField resignFirstResponder];`
`textField.text = @"";`
 `return NO;`

Comment: In `textFieldShouldClear`,  `[textField resignFirstResponder];`. That was BIG problem.. that's why I went with `NSTimer`

Comment: @FahimParkar yeah but you did not return a `NO`, that's the difference! Look closely at my comment

Answer (score 0):

***I am not sure what was the problem***, **but I solved calling the dismiss keyboard method after some interval using `NSTimer`.**

Below is what I did.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == searchTF) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(hideAllKeyboards) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void) hideAllKeyboards {
    [searchTF resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This way, after clicking the clear button, keyboard is getting dismissed.

**It would be great if someone post answer as why this is happening. I will mark that answer as accepted.**

---

### Edit 1

As per Daniel answer, I did below.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == searchTF) {
        isFilterOn.text = @"no";
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        textField.text = @"";
        [self myTextFieldDidChange];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

In `myTextFieldDidChange`, I am showing the filtered list and un-filtered list based on the text I have in `UITextField`.

Comment: I think this is because the `textFieldShouldClear` -method does invoke a call of `textFieldDidBeginEditing` because a clear is also an edit. Therefor the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is firing a `becomeFirstResponder` and the keyboard doesn't get dismissed. You could test this out by implementing all delegate methods of `UITextField` and set some breakpoints.

Comment: simply use [self.view endEditing:YES] that hide your keyBoard

Comment: @NitinGohel : Already did, still not working... I have already updated question for the same... Check Daniel answer for the reason...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your textfield IBOutlet is properly connected ,Although you can try

> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];